# Cannot add any virtio discs in virt-manager, how to fix?

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I’ve just freshly installed virt-manager and libvirt-bin (and related packages) on a Debian sid system, and have a strange problem I’ve not yet seen on another similar installation:

When creating a new VM, I get presented one with an IDE disc and an RTL8139 NIC. I can change the type of the NIC to virtio, no problem, but I cannot add a virtio disc. All I get offered are IDE disc/CD, Floppy, SCSI disc, USB disc.

How to fix this? Am I unexpectedly missing any supplementary packages?

Clarification: I’ve got a disc image which I can add to the VM, no problem, just I’d like to add it as virtio disc, not as IDE disc. No filesystem permission problems or anything.

Comment: [This mailing list poster had the same problem](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2011-May/msg00094.html) yet received no answer either…

Comment: I managed a workaround using `virsh edit $domain` but this is, of course, no solution… (but at least, the VM came up cleanly with `/dev/vda` usable).

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Report it in debian's BZ

Comment: @dyasny I can’t reproduce it on another system though. I’m running Debian sid at work too, and (even after dist-upgrading today) the virt-manager setup on this box is able to add Virtio discs, LUNs, etc.

Comment: There is nothing that would block virtio. If it doesn't show up, I'd start looking at the code, and that usually means a bug. Try to update both hosts to the same patch level to make sure you are running the same code in both locations

Comment: @dyasny: Debian does _not_ use Bugzilla, so there is no "Debian's BZ".

Comment: @XTaran ok, whatever bugtracking tool Debian developers use, does it matter really?

Comment: @dyasny: No, but IMHO it's not OK to mix up generic descriptive terms with brand names, trademarks or specific implementations. It's like saying "Fix your Apache" to a guy running nginx or lighttpd.

Comment: ok, whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and came up with this solution:

Check: Is kvm really enabled in your bios?? Run this: `dmesg | grep kvm`

If it says `kvm: disabled by bios` go to the bios and enable it! in virt-manager you can now select kvm as emulator for new machines. I just recreated my machine without modifying the image and now virtio is available for disks.

What confused me for quite a while is that `vmx` is shown in `/proc/cpuinfo` even if VT is disabled in the bios so I did not check there first.